# Weird Error with Entity Framework and SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I try updating my database it fails with the error

> {"constraint failed\r\nUNIQUE constraint failed: Accounts.AccountID"}

The weird thing is that if I empty the db of all its records then it will work once and the next time fail.
Here is the code:

```
//parameter is the current view model that is displayed
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    using (var db = new mainEntities())
    {
        var vm = (NewAccountViewModel)parameter;
        decimal balance = 0;
        decimal.TryParse(vm.Balance, out balance);

        db.Accounts.Add(new Account() {
                    FirstName = vm.FirstName,
                    LastName = vm.LastName,
                    Balance = balance
                });

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public partial class Account
{
    public long AccountID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

I used the VS SQLite Toolbox extension to create the table and the SQL code it generated is:

```
CREATE TABLE [Accounts] (
  [AccountID] INTEGER NOT NULL
, [FirstName] TEXT NOT NULL
, [LastName] TEXT NOT NULL
, [Balance] NUMERIC NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_master_PK_Accounts] PRIMARY KEY ([AccountID])
, CONSTRAINT [PK_Accounts] PRIMARY KEY ([AccountID])
);
```

Comment: Can you share the constructor of Account class?

Comment: Straight forward, you are doing something which is against the unique constraint, might be possible you were trying to insert null/duplicate value. Its already been answered question @SO. So, search it before posting a question.

Comment: I added what I could find. Unless you can tell me where it might have auto generated the constructer

Comment: In Execute you do db.Accounts.Add(..). I don't see any code where you do an update of an existing record. Among other things you should study the code in mainEntities().

Comment: I was not trying to update, all I wanted to do was add an account to the database

Comment: Share the structure and the constraints of your accounts table.

Comment: This could be due to the fact that you have not set Store Generation Pattern to Identity for your PK.

Comment: I edited the question to include the SQL that created the Table in the database.

Comment: I also tried redoing the table with deleting the `, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_master_PK_Accounts] PRIMARY KEY ([AccountID])` But it added the table and the sqlite_master_PK_Accounts anyway without me telling it to

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid and @dotNET I tried adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` but it did not seem to help at all